# 1 button toggle for multiple texts with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

Hello,

I am trying to make one button to toggle some text, and I want the text to change related to an id.

So 1 button to toggle on/off the text, while the text changes according to a id

Is it possible ?

**EDIT :**

I have on one side a slideshow with which I can change the image displayed , and on the other side one text about the image current image. I also want to change the text as the same time as the image changes.

I also have a button use for toggle on/off the text and I don't want the text to be displayed when the website load for the first time.

How can text and image change at the same time but the text only be display when the toggle button is hit ?

For the HTML I have :

```
  <img class="mySlides" src="img/bouc.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <p class="img-name">BOUC 1</p>
  <div class="txt-div" id="1">
    <p>Text 1</p></p>
  </div>

  <img class="mySlides" src="img/bouc.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <p class="img-name">BOUC 2</p>
  <div class="txt-div" id="2">
    <p>Text 2</p></p>
  </div>

  <button class="chat-button w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"></button>
  <button class="chat-button w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)"></button>  
  <button class="chat-button-txt">Text</button>
```

For the CSS I have :

```
.txt-div{
...
display: none;
...
}
```

For the JS I have :

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("img-count");
    var txt = document.getElementsByClassName("txt-div");
    var noms = document.getElementsByClassName("img-name");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
     dots[i].style.display = "none";
     noms[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  noms[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".chat-button-txt").click(function(){
        $(".txt-div").toggle();
        });
    });
}
```

I don't know how to make the text change as the same time as "x", "dots" and "noms" while only be display when toggle by the "chat-button-txt"

Someone has an idea ?

Comment: the question is unclear

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by add anothe class to "mask" the text with the toggle button and the text can change as the same time as images are changing but isn't a "better way" to do so ?

My actual code :

HTML

```
<div class="cover-txt"></div>
  <img class="mySlides" src="img/bouc.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <p class="img-name">BOUC 1</p>
  <div class="txt-div" id="1">
    <p>Text 1</p>
  </div>

  <img class="mySlides" src="img/bouc.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <p class="img-name">BOUC 2</p>
  <div class="txt-div" id="2">
    <p>Text 2</p>
  </div>

<button class="chat-button w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"></button>
  <button class="chat-button w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)"></button>  
  <button class="chat-button-txt">Text</button>
```

CSS

```
.cover-txt{
position: absolute;
background-color: white;
display: block;
top:10%;
left:104%;
width: 22vw;
height: 25vw;
z-index: 999;
}
```

JS

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}
function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("img-count");
    var txt = document.getElementsByClassName("txt-div");
    var noms = document.getElementsByClassName("img-name");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
     dots[i].style.display = "none";
     noms[i].style.display = "none";
     txt[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  noms[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  txt[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".chat-button-txt").click(function(){
        $(".cover-txt").toggle();
        });
    });
}
```

I think it's not the best solution but I worked for me. If anyone has something better I'll be glad to read it.

Thank you very much,

Regards,

U